# Transfer at Narita: Enough time to get my flight?

Tags: transit, short-connections, nrt

I will be arriving at Narita on American Airlines at 3:05.

I need to catch a Delta flight at 5:25.

Is this enough time?

Comment: The issue might be IF you can check your bags through.  Is it one ticket or two?  If you have to claim bags, and clear immigration to check in, it will add time needed.

Comment: @Tom She cannot check her bags through. Delta and AA no longer have an interline relationship. But with no bags, she can check in without difficulty in the international transfers area, there is a full check in desk there.

Comment: That seems like a really unlikely transit combination for Narita.  Where are you flying to and from?  And are you sure those are actually American/Delta flights, or just codeshares?

Comment: @Calchas - Normally that is the case, but Delta has been changing some flights through Tokyo and where they have dropped flights they have rebooked pre-existing customers on flights with other carriers.  And as I was told luggage will be checked through for those customers.

Comment: @Tom As far as I am aware, Delta and AA do not have the legal agreement in place necessary to through check bags. Moreover they do not interline at a ticket level, so Delta would actually have to go and buy a revenue AA ticket like you or me. I would therefore be very surprised if they are routing people onto AA.

Comment: @calchas I only know what they told when they rebooked my BKK-NRT leg onto ANA.  This is not normal procedure but rather due to dropped routes.  AA is one of airlines being used by Delta so not if that is the OP's situation.

Answer (score 8):

American airlines almost always operates out of terminal 2 (not certain code share flights). Delta almost always operates out of terminal 1 (not certain code share flights). So you will arrive in terminal 2 at 3:05 and have a little more than 2 hours before your flight leaves from terminal 1.

[Here](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/connect/inter/inter_inter_t2.html) is a very handy guide for procedures when arriving at terminal 2.
After getting of the plane you just follow signs for International transfers. (I am assuming given your choice of airlines). There you will have to go through a security check and an x-ray of your carry one baggage.

From there it is easy to use the Terminal shuttle bus to get to terminal 1. The buss takes about 15 minutes to get to the terminal. When you get to your new terminal just check for the gate and proceed to it.

So yes. Unless something spectacular happens, it does not take even close to 2 hours to go through security and take a 15 minute bus ride. But as one should always do in case of transfers walk straight to the security line then take the bus as fast as you can.

Normally this will leave you plenty of time in your new terminal to browse or get some rest. But in case of lines you will be as fast as you can.

IF, by any chance you inbound flight is running late it is quite common that someone would be standing at your path to security or at security and check for people with short connections and help them as much as they can.

Comment: In this case the passenger is connecting across two tickets, since AA and DL do not have an interline relationship. I know that the staff at Narita are fantastic but I doubt even they will spot that the passenger is making an offline self-connection.